# runOn followed by subscribeOn FLUX not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, flux, reactor

My flow goes like this I'm doing Sqs polling on seperate thread  using Flux.generate and I sending the flux to class which handles the flux paralelly which is not working

My Poller goes like this

```
return Flux.generate(synchronousSink -> {
        log.info(queueName + " queue Polling ...");
        List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(receive_request).getMessages();
        synchronousSink.next(messages);
    })

            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
```

and my operations on the flux goes like this

```
  events.parallel()
            .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .doOnNext(t->log.info("Not printing anything"))
            .subscribe();
```

The events are not getting after runOn if I removed runOn they are working fine can any one help me here 
Note -"I'm using subscibeOn in poller and runOn in Other class does this cause any issue"

Comment: Polling SQS using the old aws sdk library is a blocking IO operation. It shouldn't be running on parallel scheduler. Try to switch to bounded elastic Scheduler in the subscribeOn operator.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi  The solution is working but after some time I dont know its still the same thing the execution is not going to down stream

Comment: I'm assuming some kind of deadlock happens somewhere in the pipeline.Try to avoid running blocking IO operations on parallel thread. If you can share more of your code there is a better chance I can help.